# Unable to filter out snapshots using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I need to actually delete a certain snapshots which have the tags_description . I make use of following code :

```
def call_cleaner(data):
    regions = ['us-west-2', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1']
    for index, region in enumerate(regions):
        for ip_address, tags_descrip, regions_az, volume_id in data[index]:
            client = boto3.client('ec2',region,aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
            delete_snapshot = client.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag-value', 'Values':[tags_descrip]}])
            for snap in delete_snapshot['Snapshots']:
                print snap
            #    print "Deleting snapshot %s" % snap['SnapshotId']
            #   ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snap['SnapshotId'])
```

but this code is not able to filter out any snapshot that i am interested in deleting. Infact it doesn't print anything. I have snapshots with the tags_descrip on my account though. Please help

Comment: are you sure the `tags_descrip` is on the value pair of the Tag key/value pair ? can you quickly try with `tag_key` instead. if it does not work but you know at least 1 snapshot with the expected value, run the `ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-id <id>` and check the result or paste it in your question

Comment: ok, i tried with `  delete_snapshot = client.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values':[tags_descrip]}])` and it doesn't return me anything either.

Comment: how/where do i run ec2 `describe-snapshots --snapshot-id <id>`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Actually the resourse has no key ,, i need the description